# JBehave Vs FitNesse

Tags: bdd, functional-testing, fitnesse, jbehave

If your system is basically crunching numbers i.e. given a set of large inputs, run a process on them, and then assert the outputs, which is the better framework for this?

By 'large inputs', I mean we need to enter data for several different, related entities.

Also, there are several outputs i.e. we don't just get one number at the end.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you find yourself talking through different examples with people, JBehave is probably pretty good.

If you find yourself making lists of numbers and comparing inputs with outputs, Fitnesse is probably better.

However, if you find yourself talking to other devs and nobody else, use plain old JUnit. The less abstraction you have, the quicker it will be to run and the easier it will be to maintain.

Comment: Awesome answer! I'd like to say that this advice "...talking to other devs and nobody else, use plain jUnit.. the less abstraction you have, the quicker it will be.." True for JS, a more mature / professional dev community. As a PHP / WordPress dev: Use Codeception, not PHPunit. Our babel like [WordPress] world needs MORE abstraction to be comprehesible. See wordpress-bdd.com .

Comment: The answer I gave here is 4 years and 6 months old which means it's at least 4 years out of date. I don't think anyone uses Fitnesse, but the tables in JBehave and Cucumber serve the same purpose. And I still use XUnit for whatever variant of XUnit is current: https://github.com/lunivore/sudoque/blob/master/Sudoque.Scenarios/PlayerCanEnterElementsIntoTheGrid.cs